# Function for matching values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following test data:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
thresh = .3
df2['matches'] = np.where(df2.A - df2.B < thresh,1,0)
```

I created the `df2['matches']` column showing a value of `1` when `df2.A - df2.B < thresh`.

```
        A           B            C      matches
0   0.501554    -0.589855   -0.751568   0
1   -0.295198   0.512442    0.466915    1
2   0.074863    0.343388    -1.700998   1
3   0.115432    -0.507847   -0.825545   0
4   1.013837    -0.007333   -0.292192   0
5   -0.930738   1.235501    -0.652071   1
6   -1.026615   1.389294    0.035041    1
7   0.969147    -0.397276   1.272235    0
8   0.120461    -0.634686   -1.123046   0
9   0.956896    -0.345948   -0.620748   0
10  -0.552476   1.376459    0.447807    1
11  0.882275    0.490049    0.713033    0
```

However, I actually would like to compare all three columns and if the values are within `thresh` it will return a number corresponding with the amount of matches in `df2['matches]`.

So for example if Col A = 1, B = 2 and C = 1.5 and thresh was .5 the function would return 3 in the ['matches'] column.

Is there a function that already does something similar or can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the threshold for each pair of your columns, then sum up the resulting boolean columns to obtain the number you need. Note, however, that this number depends on the order in which you compare columns. This ambiguity would be gone if you used `abs(df['A']-df['B'])` etc, and this might very well be your intention. Below I'll assume this is what you need.

Generally, you can use `itertools.combinations` to produce each pair of columns once:

```
from itertools import combinations
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
thresh = .3
df['matches'] = sum(abs(df[k1]-df[k2])<thresh for k1,k2 in combinations(df.keys(),2))
```

The generator expression in the `sum()` loops over every column pair, and constructs the respective boolean vector. These are summed for each column pair, and the resulting column is appended to the dataframe.

Example output for `thresh = 0.3`:

```
           A         B         C  matches
0   0.146360 -0.099707  0.633632        1
1   1.462810 -0.186317 -1.411988        0
2   0.358827 -0.758619  0.038329        0
3   0.077122 -0.213856 -0.619768        1
4   0.215555  1.930888 -0.488517        0
5  -0.946557 -0.904743 -0.004738        1
6  -0.080209 -0.850830 -0.866865        1
7  -0.997710 -0.580679 -2.231168        0
8   1.762313 -0.356464 -1.813028        0
9   1.151338  0.347636 -1.323791        0
10  0.248432  1.265484  0.048484        1
11  0.559934 -0.401059  0.863616        0
```

Using `itertools.combinations`, the columns are compared as

```
>>> [k for k in itertools.combinations(df.keys(),2)]
('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
```

but this really doesn't matter if you're using the absolute value (since then the difference is symmetric with respect to columns).

Comment: Thanks @Andras Deak. Maybe there is a problem with my question though as line 10 shows 3 matches and the difference between 1.260968 and 0.690971 is > thresh. I am looking for matches when the difference between the numbers is < thresh.

Comment: @adele see my last code block: the order we have is `('B','C')`, so we compute `'B'` column minus `'C'` column, which is negative for this case. You might want to have it all the way around, by swapping `k1` and `k2` in the list comprehension (edited; now a generator expression, inside `sum()`); but the most likely case is that you need the absolute value of the difference, rather than the difference itself. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Can you pls show me how I get the absolute value of the difference and I will see if this gives the result I was expecting, thanks

Comment: @adele I'm glad I could help:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this guy:

```
df2['matches'] = df2.apply(lambda x: sum([x[i] - x[j] <= thresh for i, j in [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]]), axis=1)
```

It could be generalized to any number of columns if necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a way to do it:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
thresh = 0.3

newcol = []
for row in df2.iterrows():
     newcol.append(sum([v > thresh for v in list(row[1])]))
df2['matches'] = newcol
```

Comment: "How many columns are >thresh" would be answerable with much less work; that is not the question.